# jQuery get id of all radio buttons that are selected on a page and assign them to a variable

Tags: jquery

I have a page that will have an random number of radio box groups that are dynamically created.  I need to grab all radio boxes on submit and store them in variables.   As I don't know how many radio button groups there will be. I need to assign them dynamically and then retrieve the data.  The one information I do know is that the field id's will all start with "*chkpt_field_*"

I know the first step is to get a count of all fields.

```
var count=0    
jQuery('input[id*="chkpt_field_"]').change(function(){
    count = jQuery('input[id*="chkpt_field_"]:checked').length
});
```

Where do you go from here, I am guessing a for loop but I am not sure how you would create for loop for grabbing all fields that match an id

I was thinking of using jQuery's each function to iterate through each checked field seen on form submission, but this doesn't work... and the way I have it set would only set one value if it actually worked.

```
jQuery('input[id*="chkpt_field_]').attr('checked', true).each(function(){
    var id = (this).attr("id");
    localStorage.setItem('field1', id);

});
```

I am not looking for anyone to do my work for me as I need to learn this, but if anyone has any pointers, tips or tricks.  I would love some advice and direction.

***UPDATED***

```
      var val1 = localStorage.getItem('chkpt_$field_name');
      var itemval = jQuery('input[id='+val1+']').val();
      jQuery("#"+val1).attr('checked', true);

      jQuery(".signup_interest_form").submit(function(e){
        jQuery('input[id*="chkpt_field_"]:checked').each(function() {
          localStorage.setItem('chkpt_$field_name', jQuery('input[name="chkpt_$field_name"]:checked').attr('id'));

        });

      });

    jQuery('input[name="chkpt_$field_name"]').change(function(e){ 
      jQuery('input[name="$field_name"]').val(jQuery(e.currentTarget).data('value'));
        jQuery('input[name="$field_name"]').trigger('change');
      });
```

This updates and set the fields to checked, but when I try to submit the form no data is being passed, it is as though the form data is not being set at all.

I have updated some more, it checks the fields. but the values are still not there. When it submits it sends no information

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      var val1 = localStorage.getItem('chkpt_$field_name');
      var itemval = jQuery('input[id='+val1+']').val();
      jQuery("#"+val1).prop('checked', 'checked').prop('checked', 'checked');

      jQuery(".signup_interest_form").submit(function(e){

        if (!jQuery('input[name="chkpt_$field_name"]:checked').val() ) 
        {
          jQuery('input[name="chkpt_$field_name"]').parents('.frm_toggle_container').toggle()
          jQuery('input[name="chkpt_$field_name"]').parents('div.frm_section_heading').children('h3').css("color", "red")
          return false;
        } else {

            jQuery('input[id*="chkpt_field_"]:checked').each(function() {
            localStorage.setItem('chkpt_$field_name', jQuery('input[name="chkpt_$field_name"]:checked').attr('id'));

          });
        }


      });
      jQuery('input[name="chkpt_$field_name"]').change(function(e){ 
      jQuery('input[name="$field_name"]').val(jQuery(e.currentTarget).data('value'));
        jQuery('input[name="$field_name"]').trigger('change');
      });

    });
```

Comment: You might want to have a look at the map function.  What you're doing right now is doing a loop that will just reassign what's going in localStorage with each iteration.  You don't want to loop, you just want to grab everything and store it, which is what map is good for.

Comment: Okay, i will look in to that.   My other though was to push everything to an array like this.  

          var arr = []

          jQuery('input[id*="chkpt_field_]:checked').each(function(){
            arr.push($(this).val()); 
          });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I just need to make the request as an Ajax request and prevent page reload and that solved the problem without going through a bunch of extra work.

Answer (score 0):

I found that pushing it into an array and retrieving the array and then assigning accomplished by task

Here is the code I used.

```
var arr = [];
    if(localStorage.getItem("array")!==null){


    //test
    var val1 = localStorage.getItem('array');

      var stringArray = val1.split(',')
        jQuery.each(stringArray, function(index,item){
        jQuery("#"+item).attr('checked', true);
      });
    }     


    jQuery(".signup_interest_form").submit(function(e){
      jQuery('input[id*="chkpt_field_"]:checked').each(function() {

        arr.push(this.id);
      });
      localStorage.setItem('array', arr);
    });
```